# how to break lines when I concatenate strings in django

Tags: python, django, programming-languages, string-concatenation, line-breaks

hy guys, I needed again of the help of you. Now i want to make a break line when i concatenate strings, i tried to do of this way:

```
    r['placa_desc'] = PessoaFrota(request,dbcur).get_placa_choices(r.get('placa'))
    if r.get('placa_desc'):
        r['placa'] =   \n + r.get('placa_desc')[0]
```

but when i try to make this, i got this error:

Exception Value:
unexpected character after line continuation character (views.py, line 250)

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote your \n:

```
r['placa'] =   \n + r.get('placa_desc')[0]

r['placa'] =   "\n" + r.get('placa_desc')[0]
```

or python thinks the \ is a continuation character.  Try that.

Comment: thank's now i can make the concatenate but when i try print this dont work =(

Comment: What do you mean 'dont work'? Does it print anything? Do you get an error message? What OS are you using? Actually, start a new question (and tick the box that says I've answered this one!).

Comment: Were you expecting to see this in your web browser?

Comment: I need return a value (plate of a car) and your description with a breakline, with your help i do this. but on the html has a function called regroup, and the value and the description are printed in the same line ¬¬.

Comment: Hy spacedman, I can do this value be printed in the screen, but with another way =/ i acces this value on this way: 

{{ placa.list.0.placa_desc.0 }} 

Dont are a pretty way but works =D

Answer (score 2):

you missed '', it should be:

```
 r['placa_desc'] = PessoaFrota(request,dbcur).get_placa_choices(r.get('placa'))
    if r.get('placa_desc'):
        r['placa'] =   '\n' + r.get('placa_desc')[0]
```